# Relation between Ricci curvature and sectional curvature for 3-manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 3-manifolds, ricci-curvature

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold. It is well known that if $sec(M)\geq \kappa$ then $Ric(M)\geq (n-1)\kappa$.

If I understand correctly in dimensions $n\geq 4$ a lower bound on $Ric(M)$ does not imply a lower bound on $sec(M)$. However in $n=2$ this implication  is true for trivial reason.

**Is it true that in $n=3$ a lower bound on $Ric(M)$ implies a lower bound on $sec(M)$?**

Comment: @GabeK: I am aware of this formula. But it contains different signs, and I do not see if it implies my question. However this formula does imply that an upper bound on absolute value of Ricci curvature implies an upper bound on absolute value of the Riemann curvature tensor, and hence an upper bound on absolute value of sectional curvature.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I had misread the question to be whether one could find bounds on the sectional curvature from two-sided bounds on the Ricci curvature (not merely lower bounds). As the answer points out, this is definitely not the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is definitely false. In dimension 3 if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are eigenvalues of the curvature operator then Ricci curvatures of eigenvectors are $\lambda_1+\lambda_2, \lambda_1+\lambda_3, \lambda_2+\lambda_3$.  If one of $\lambda_i$'s is very negative but the other two are very positive then all these sums can be bounded below. Every algebraic curvature tensor can be realized at a point so locally this can definitely happen. Complete examples exist too. I can't seem to find a reference to an explicit example but it's well known that there are examples of metrics on $\mathbb R^3$ with $Ric\ge 0$ which have some negative sectional curvature. If you rescale such metric by a small number Ricci curvature remains nonnegative but sectional curvature can become arbitrary negative in some 2-planes.

Comment: How $\lambda_i$'s are related to sectional curvature?

Comment: in general they will be some linear combinations of sectional curvatiures but as I said every algebraic curvature tensor can be realized and you can take one where eigenvectors are $e_1\wedge e_2, e_1\wedge e_3, e_2\wedge e_3$. Then $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ will be just sectional curvatures in those directions.

Comment: sorry, it's even easier than that. this is dimension 3 so every 2-vector is decomposable and hence every eigenvalue of the curvature tensor is always a sectional curvature.